# Is it possible send in a file while running a kubectl job?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible send in a file into the job pod while running a kubectl job from the local system which is running the kubectl job?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the

```
kubectl cp --help
Copy files and directories to and from containers.

Examples:
  # !!!Important Note!!!
  # Requires that the 'tar' binary is present in your container
  # image.  If 'tar' is not present, 'kubectl cp' will fail.

  # Copy /tmp/foo_dir local directory to /tmp/bar_dir in a remote pod in the default namespace
  kubectl cp /tmp/foo_dir <some-pod>:/tmp/bar_dir

  # Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in a specific container
  kubectl cp /tmp/foo <some-pod>:/tmp/bar -c <specific-container>

  # Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in namespace <some-namespace>
  kubectl cp /tmp/foo <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/bar

  # Copy /tmp/foo from a remote pod to /tmp/bar locally
  kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar

Options:
  -c, --container='': Container name. If omitted, the first container in the pod will be chosen
      --no-preserve=false: The copied file/directory's ownership and permissions will not be preserved in the container

Usage:
  kubectl cp <file-spec-src> <file-spec-dest> [options]

Use "kubectl options" for a list of global command-line options (applies to all commands).
```

This is similar to `docker cp`.

Comment: I am aware of this command. But kubectl job is a one time process. It creates a pod, does the job and exits. I am looking for a way to copy the file as part of the job.

Comment: So you want `kubectl run --pass-some-file /path`.. I see. There's no way to do this. If this is a configuration string you can either pass it via env var, or ConfigMap mounted as a file into a pod. Otherwise I suggest putting a file on S3 or somewhere and get it inside a job

Comment: For config map: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44815#issuecomment-297077509