# One-off kubectl run with file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to execute a **one-off** in a Kubernetes cluster, however using a file from the local file system. Something like:

```
kubectl run mytmpjob --rm --restart='Never' \
  --command <some-command-which-acts-on-a-file-uploaded-from-local>
```

I like the convenience that `kubectl run --rm` gives me since this is a one-off.

It seems to me that I need a combination of `kubectl cp` and `kubectl run` but I cannot see how? How do I get the file into the container when it doesn't exist until the point of the `kubectl run` command?

Comment: Could `kubectl apply -f job.yaml` be what you are looking for? The command starts a pod from the job.yaml, which would have to be a kubernetes job resource that does what you need. Check out [this tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/kubernetes-job).

Comment: @CloudWatcher: How is that a one-shot thing? I would have to await the Job to complete and then make sure it is removed. I would also have to figure out how to make my local file available to the job execution _before_ such execution actually starts. I don't doubt it can be done, but it would require a significant amount of scripting, right?

Comment: There is a [cleanup mechanism](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20this%20mechanism,after%20the%20Job%20has%20finished.) for jobs. As for copying files the way you describe, according to the comments for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55594452/21164658), it seems impossible, sadly (if I understood your intent correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with for ***one-time-execution-with-local-file*** pattern:

1. Generate a random unique name for the Pod.
2. Start a pod with name from step1 (using `kubectl run`) but just let it stay up doing nothing but make sure it is immediately interruptible. This is done for example using a Bash command such as `trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait`  (YMMV, e.g. Alpine Linux does not support this syntax). The image you use must of course additionally include the tools/binaries you need to actually perform the real execution (step 5).
3. Wait for the pod to exist (unfortunately, kubectl cannot directly do this) and then wait for it to be `Ready` (the latter can be done using `kubectl wait`).
4. Copy the file(s) into the pod. This is done using `kubectl cp`.
5. Execute in the pod what it is you actually want to execute. This is done using `kubectl exec` command.
6. Remove the pod. This is done using `kubectl delete pod` with your unique pod name.

This methodology works and you can implement it (and generalize it) in your favorite scripting language for use in say a CI/CD pipeline. In order not to leave something behind, you would need to make sure that if step 2 is executed with success then step 6 *must* be executed regardless if there are errors in steps 3-5  (pattern known as "[finalizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer)" in some languages).

The above can be seen as an enhanced version of `kubectl run` meaning that execution happens synchronously: it awaits the execution of the command in the container.

If you know of a simpler/smarter way to implement this pattern in Kubernetes, let us know. :-)

Comment: As it sounds like you want to run that manually in the terminal I'd suggest to use the script as a custom [kubectl plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubectl/kubectl-plugins/#writing-kubectl-plugins), that way you could simple have something like `kubectl one-off -f path/to/file` which executes those steps for you.

Comment: @Chris. Nope, execution not manual in terminal, but from a CI pipeline. Anyway, great idea about the kubectl plugin mechanism. Not sure if I would get enough benefit from it, though (as opposed to just executing a script). But thx.